# Devexpress ListBoxControl Scroll Events

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, devexpress

I have a `listboxcontrol` where I'm inserting Log text
and display always the last lines

```
listBoxControl1.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl1.Items.Count - 1;
```

but when the user scolls up/down the list, I wish to maintain the user's scroll position
,
a condition to cancel the code above

I tried with `MouseUp` / `MouseDown` but these event won't fire on clicking the `ScrollBar`

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxControl1.Items.Add(e.UserState);
        if (!mouseDown) // this is not working !!
            listBoxControl1.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to skip `listBoxControl1.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl1.Items.Count - 1;` this when user is performing scroll(up/down) ??

Comment: where you have written "listBoxControl1.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl1.Items.Count - 1;"?.................in which event?

Comment: @Anandkumar , on backgroundworker_ProgressChanged after listBoxControl1.Items.Add(e.UserState);

Comment: when the user it's doing nothing I want to keep this logic (always the last Items will be seen), but when the User wants to see the first elements and the process is still working, I want to pass code SelectedIndex = ...

Comment: It is usually done with a help from toggle button to allow/disallow automatic scrolling because this solution will not be able to restart automatic scrolling.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović  yes, this can be a solution , please answer , and if any idea won't show , i will do it your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the following approach:

```
SubscribeScrollEvent(listBoxControl1);    // Before start items adding
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
//...
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    UnsubscribeScrollEvent(listBoxControl1);  // After items adding complete 
}
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    listBoxControl1.Items.Add(e.ProgressPercentage);
    if(!userScrollPerformed)
        listBoxControl1.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl1.Items.Count - 1;
}
//...
void SubscribeScrollEvent(ListBoxControl listBox) {
    var hScroll = listBox.Controls[0] as DevExpress.XtraEditors.HScrollBar;
    var vScroll = listBox.Controls[1] as DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar;
    vScroll.Scroll += ListBox_Scroll;
    hScroll.Scroll += ListBox_Scroll;
}
void UnubscribeScrollEvent(ListBoxControl listBox) {
    var hScroll = listBox.Controls[0] as DevExpress.XtraEditors.HScrollBar;
    var vScroll = listBox.Controls[1] as DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar;
    vScroll.Scroll -= ListBox_Scroll;
    hScroll.Scroll -= ListBox_Scroll;
}
bool userScrollPerformed;
void ListBox_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack)
        userScrollPerformed = true; // set a flag
}
```